# How to re-model the existing data model for a document oriented db like ravendb or mongodb

Tags: database-design, mongodb, ravendb, document-oriented-db

Assume the following scenario (with relational databases),

```
class Currency
{
long id;
String code;
String name;
}

class OrderGroup
{
long id;
Collection<Order> Orders;
}

class Order
{
long id;
long currency;
}
```

in the practical scenario there will be large number of Orders (with ever growing numbers). What would be the optimum way to convert this to support a document based db. There is a option to change the currency code and name and when it happens will it be updated automatically across all the orders if the currency is added as a child of order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modeling relational database in document databases, it helps if you think in DDD term "[Aggregates](http://thinkddd.com/glossary/aggregate-root/)" and think how changing the value of an object will be handled, e.g. the object is either an [Enitty or a Value Object](http://thinkddd.com/blog/2009/02/14/entities-and-value-objects/), so in this case if you want changes of Currency affect existing orders, currency is NOT a value object and you just put a reference to the Currency object used in Order, somehow like the Relational Model. Model it like this will work in RavenDb:

OrderGroup aggregate:

```
public class OrderGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Currency Entity:

```
public class Currency 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note, however, that modelling it like this you'll need separate queries to fetch/update the related objects.